# How do I make my bot delete a message when it contains a certain word?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

Okay so I'm trying to make a filter for my bot, but one that isn't too complicated.
I've got this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx,message):
    if 'fuck' in Message.content.lower:
        Message.delete()
```

But it gives the error:

```
    Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event        
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Could you guys help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) event handler only gets passed a single [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) object, not a [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) object.

Comment: what should i use then?

Comment: you should still use [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message). You only need to modify the parameters. Change `on_message(ctx, message)` to `on_message(message)`

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Is what im getting now

Comment: GOT IT! I had to add a () after message.content.lower:

Comment: [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) is a function, yes.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete), the delete function has to be awaited.
What I've also noticed in your code is that you are capitalizing `message` when the argument to the function passed is lowercase.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'fuck' in message.content.lower:
        await message.delete()
```

This should work now.

Comment: Thank you! i put Message in capital because i saw another example saying that!

Comment: `on_message` only receives one message parameter.