# Why doesn't python allow me to use 2 arguments in discord.py?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

Okay so im making a filter for my discord. and after about 2 hours i figured out how to delete the message.

but i've realised that i cant use 2 arguments.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx,message):
if 'cancer' in message.content.lower():
    await message.delete()
    bad = discord.Embed(title='YOU SAID A NO NO WORD!!!', description ='Dont do that again or you\'ll 
    have some problems <a:Sippp:668488891820408862>', colour=discord.Color.red())
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=bad)
```

When i do this, i cant use both ctx and message. Could someone help me out?

The reason i reuse this and its similar to another question of mine is because its not explained there, and because its not only handy to know for others, if they arent looking for that precise question.

Comment: I believe `ctx` is only for commands not events. The `on_message` event is just the message, there is no more context to give there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make my bot delete a message when it contains a certain word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809874/how-do-i-make-my-bot-delete-a-message-when-it-contains-a-certain-word)

Answer (score 0):

`on_message` should take a single argument, the message sent ([docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)).

If you need to access the channel the message was sent in, you can use `message.channel` ([see channel attribute in the message section of the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel)). So your function becomes:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
if 'cancer' in message.content.lower():
    await message.delete()
    bad = discord.Embed(title='YOU SAID A NO NO WORD!!!', description ='Dont do that again or you\'ll 
    have some problems <a:Sippp:668488891820408862>', colour=discord.Color.red())
    await message.channel.send(embed=bad)
```